# Spring Data find by column that is not in entity

Tags: sql, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

1)

```
Person

int id
String name

@JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
List<Email> emailList;
```

2)

```
Email

int id
String emailAddress
```

In Email table, I have three columns - `id`, `emailAddress`, `person_id`.

My question is - can I write a SpringData method in `EmailRepository` like - `findByEmailAddressAndPersonIdNotNull(String emailAddress)`

or do I have to write a custom `@Query`?

I need to find email by column person_id.

Comment: You are postiing three different questions. 
In the title: "find by column that is not in entity"
In main part: "find by property in referenced entity"
In last sentence: "find single attribute by column without matching attribute in entity"
Which question do you really want to ask?

Comment: use native query

Answer (score 1):

`findByEmailListEmailAddressAndPersonIdNotNull(String emailAddress)` or `findByEmailList_EmailAddressAndPersonIdNotNull(String emailAddress)`

should work.

Comment: I have to write it in Email or Person repo? My question is - I need in Email repo find Email entity that has specific emailAddress and person_id not null

Comment: for that you need a custom query